# Data saved in mongodb but not reflecting in robo3t

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I run a mongoose query of 'findOne' and 'save'. There is no error in the query and when I test it in the postman, it also returns true. But when I tried to check the value in robo3t, it shows the same old entry. I refresh the robo3t multiple times but it shows the same old data. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

```
User.findOne({ _id }, (err, user) => {
        if (user) {
            if (user.lastSubscriptionStatus === true) {
            user.lastSubscription.expiredDate.setDate(user.lastSubscription.expiredDate.getDate()+parseFloat(days));
                user.save()
                    .then((data) => {
                        console.log("User saved "+data); //here i see the updated date value
                        freeDaysStatus = true;
                        resolve(freeDaysStatus);
                    })
                    .catch(() => {
                        console.log("User not saved");
                        freeDaysStatus = false;
                        resolve(freeDaysStatus);
                    })
            }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

if ta db is only to test; delete there (not just the collection) Because I already had this problem and I had to delete the db because even if I did ctrl r; it was not working and by removing it it solved all my problems I hope it will work :)